# Python : function to find maximum even digit in string

Tags: python, function

Hoping to find a way so the function returns the maximum/biggest even digit in (st) as a result and if (st) does not have an even digit, the function returns -3 as a result. All/any help is greatly appreciated. The code below was my attempt at it and does not get the result i'm hoping for, just starting to learn how to use python. Thank you. I'm using python 3.6

```
def maximumeven(st):
    Result = 0
    for i in (st):
        if i.isdigit():
            if (int(i) % 2 == 0):
                Result = Result + int(max(i))
            return Result
print(maximum("124A2"))
```

Comment: Your code currently adds any even integer to the result.  Is that intended?  In other words, do you want the sum of the even digits?  What is the desired output of `maximumeven("124A2")`? 4?

Comment: Not intended, just looking for the highest single digit even number in st.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post questions that essentially ask us to do your homework for you. Instead, post specific questions about what is confusing you.

Comment: Do you want the maximum single digit integer, or can consecutive digits be combined?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you really just want the biggest even **digit**, then since there are only five single-digit even numbers, I'd just use:

```
def maximumeven(st):
    if "8" in st:
        return 8
    if "6" in st:
        return 6
    if "4" in st:
        return 4
    if "2" in st:
       return 2
    if "0" in st:
       return 0

    return -3

print(maximumeven("124A2")) #4
print(maximumeven("13579")) #-3
print(maximumeven("2468")) #8
```

A much more efficient solution that only iterates over the string once and exits early if 8 is reached:

```
def maximumeven(st):
    largest = - 3
    for i in st:
        if i in '02468' and int(i) >largest:
            largest = int(i) 
        if largest == 8:
            break
    return largest
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Very inefficient. Scans the string 5 times.

Comment: True, this solution does value clarity and simplicity over efficiency.

Comment: This is a simple enough problem that you can have both.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:.

```
def maximumeven(st):
    Result = []
    for i in (st):
        if i.isdigit():
            if (int(i) % 2 == 0):
                Result.append(int(i))

    if not len(Result):
        Result = -3
    return Result
func = maximumeven("124dsd89")
print(max(func) if type(func) is list else func)
```

output: 8

Comment: Tried that but the result should be the biggest even digit from the string and if there is no single even digit, it should return -3. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: Appending a list is *completely* unnecessary. Your `max(i)` call does nothing.

Comment: Just act according to coding Ethics. if your answer is such a foolish then just accept them and try to improve. max(i) can be removed. I just adapted code in question as answer